# Checking network connection throughout app (titanium)

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am able to do this ok in single controller files:

```
Ti.Network.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    networkIsOnline = e.online;
    networkType = e.networkType;

    alert(networkIsOnline);
});
```

However, what is the best way to have this event listener, listen globally - so that I don't have to keep on copying and pasting that code?

Cheers.

Comment: This is already a global event listener. Can you provide more details of what the problem is?

Comment: I have a series of controllers. When each controller loads up, I am unable to get an updated value of the network change, because that segment of code is not executed. The only work around to do this, is to copy and past the code into every controller and update the view on an adhoc bases.

Comment: Solved the problem, basically store it in the base controller (which all children are derived from)..I am using a navigation window. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Alloy you can use a global variable. I do this:

```
Alloy.Globals.online = Ti.Network.online;
Ti.Network.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
    Alloy.Globals.online = e.online;
} );
```